# Properly force SSL with .htaccess, no double authentication

Tags: apache, https, mod-rewrite, htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to force SSL with `.htaccess` on a shared host. This means there I only have access to `.htaccess` and not the main `VirtualHost` configuration. I know you can put a rule in the `VirtualHost` config file to force SSL which will be picked up there (and acted upon first), preventing double authentication, but I can not get to that.

Here is the progress I have made:

## Config 1

This works pretty well but it does force double authentication if you visit `http://example.com` - once for http and then once for https. Once you are logged in, it automatically redirects `http://example.com/page1.html` to the https coutnerpart just fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.example\.com*)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]


AuthName "Locked"
AuthUserFile "/home/.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

## Config 2

If I add the following to the top of the file, it works a lot better in that it will switch to SSL before prompting for the password:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "example.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com
```

It is clever how it will use the `SSLRequireSSL` option and the `ErrorDocument 403` to redirect to the secure version of the site. My only complaint is that if you try to access `http://example.com/page1.html`, it will redirect to `https://example.com/`

So it is forcing SSL without a double-login, but it is not properly forwarding non-SSL resources to their SSL counterparts.

Regarding the first config, Insyte mentioned "*using mod_rewrite to perform a simple redirect is a bit of overkill. Use the Redirect directive instead. It's possible this may even fix your problem, as I believe mod_rewrite rules are some of the last directives to be processed, just before the file is actually grabbed from the filesystem*"

I have not had no such luck on finding a force-ssl config option with the redirect directive and so have been unable to test this theory.

Comment: Using mod_rewrite to do the HTTP to HTTPS redirection in ".htaccess" does not work as it gets done AFTER authentication.  BUT if set in server configs it happens BEFORE.   The mod_rewrite can preserve sub-page components of the redirected URL, and does not need the server name and page hardcoded into the rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have server-side execution such as php or cgi, then set your ErrorDocument to a file that does not require authentication.  This file should redirect the client to the proper location.  Apache will set several REDIRECT_ - prefixed environment variables to help you out, and the original environment is preserved -- see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html.

In your `.htaccess`, do as your second example above, but make the ErrorDocument an internal document:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "example.com"
ErrorDocument 403 /err_redirect.php
AuthName "Locked"
AuthUserFile "/home/.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
<Files /err_redirect.php>
  AuthType none
</Files>
```

Then, in that error document, send the appropriate HTTP status and Location header. Here's a simple example in php:

```
<?php
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works perfect for what I'm trying to do, I have some PHP based admintools in respective directories under `/admin/`, in `/admin/.htaccess` I have listed:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "www.example.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/admin/

AuthName "Enter your credentials"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwd/passwordfile
Require user valid-user
```

when going to non-secure `example.com/admin` it redirects it to secure `example.com/admin`, then prompts for authentication.

Comment: Clever to use your 403 directive as a redirect

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I use this now:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected area"
# your auth provider setup here
Require expr "%{ENV:HTTPS} !~ /on/i"
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect alias to preferred hostname  
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_HOST} -strmatch '%{SERVER_NAME}'"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect http:// to https://
RewriteCond expr "%{ENV:HTTPS} !~ /on/i"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Basically it grants access if `http://` is used, but redirects all requests to `https://` in this case.

I use `"%{ENV:HTTPS} !~ /on/i"` because I found some systems (e.g. behind SSL terminating proxies) don't set HTTPS to "off" as apache does with `http://`, or set it to "on" instead of "On" with `https://`.
I also added the redirect to the `SERVER_NAME`, in case somebody wants it.

I do not have a certificate for all my legacy aliases, so it is essential to redirect to the default hostname first in this case.

Comment: No... Granting access when http:// is used means that there is no password required and thus is never transmitted.