# Asked to authenticated WebDav twice when connecting to HTTPS

Tags: https, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm having the problem of double authentification on my Apache server like he has:
[Properly Force SSL with .htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/properly-force-ssl-with-htaccess-no-double-authentication)
But I want to do this via the conf files. He says he knows how to do it via conf files, but didnt explain further. I have two config files, both are activated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

_

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock
<VirtualHost *:443>

#Webdav
Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
<Directory /var/www/webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "My File Storage"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

#SSL
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
```

What am I doing wrong, why do I get double webdav-Window when connecting to `http://example.com/webdav`?

The authentification window is even telling me that **https://** example.com is asking for username and password.

[image: WebDAV Authentification Window]

I had an rewrite from www to non-www and http to https working via conf files, but I am not sure what happened to my confs and why it is broken now.
All I did was a2enmod a new site and then a2dismod the same site afterwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works again. After I did a full restore to one day before I enabled and disabled a site, it now works again. Don't ask me why...